# Azure Memcache Shim for node.js Worker Role

Tags: node.js, azure, memcached

There is a good article that explains how to access the Azure cache from a node.js web role (via the memcache shim):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2013/01/03/november-updates-to-windows-azure-powershell-cmdlets.aspx

But how can I set up the memcache shim for a node.js worker role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can access the cache via the ["Memcache Server Gateway"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914167.aspx) (without the shim).